# How to use GroupKFold with CalibratedClassifierCV?

Tags: scikit-learn

Unlike `GridSearchCV`, `CalibratedClassifierCV` doesn't seem to support passing the groups parameter to the `fit` method. I found this very old [github issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/12052) that reports this problem but it doesn't seem to be fixed yet. [The documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html#calibrating-a-classifier) makes it clear that not properly stratifying your cv folds will result in an incorrectly calibrated model. My dataset has multiple observations from the same users so I would need to use `GroupKFold` to ensure proper calibration.

Answer (score 2):

scikit-learn can take an iterable of (train, test) splits as the cv object, so just create them manually. For example:

```
my_cv = (
    (train, test) for train, test in GroupKFold(n_splits=5).split(X, groups=my_groups)
)
cal_clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(clf, cv=my_cv)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a modified version of `CalibratedClassifierCV` that addresses this issue for now. Until this is fixed in sklearn master, you can similarly modify the `fit` method of `CalibratedClassifierCV` to use `GroupKFold`. My solution can be found in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/mdbecker/5c236c820faa1b3b324cdb184f18a59e). This is based of sklearn version 0.24.1 but you can easily adapt it to your version of sklearn as needed.